# how to read a CSV file in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I want to read a CSV file in FLex and display content of file on Datagrid. plzz provide solution...

My Datagrid and columns on which i want ot display the file file content::

```
   <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dg" x="0" y="{btnBar.height}" width="100%" height="532"
                                 defaultLeafIcon="{null}" draggableColumns="false" editable="true"
                                 folderClosedIcon="{null}" folderOpenIcon="{null}"
                                 horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" itemEditBegin="onItemEditBegin(event)"
                                 itemEditEnd="processData(event)" itemOpen="onItemOpen(event.item)"
                                 resizableColumns="false" sortableColumns="false" sortExpertMode="true"
                                 verticalScrollPolicy="on">



    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="value" width="250" dataField="value"
                                           editorDataField="classValue" headerText="Values"
                                           itemEditor="ComboBoxRenderer"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="property" dataField="property" editable="true"
                                           editorDataField="SelectedItem" headerText="Property"
                                           itemEditor="PropertyComboBoxRenderer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.create a bean , parse the CSV and add it to the bean(properties same as no of coulmns).
2.add the bean to List iteratively.
3.pass the list as dataprovider to Datagrid